# Hibernate: bidirectionality vs. unidirectionality, depending on relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

Reading a wiki page about Hibernate I elaborated some perplexing conclusions:

```
1) Bidirectionality is reccomended in one-to-many

2) Bidirectionality is optional in many-to-one

3) Bidirectionality is normally present in many-to-many

4) Unidirectionality is reccomended in one-to-one relationships, 
using as owner class the one with the primary key of the 
relation (not the foreign key).
```

Are these statements true? Do you have any example to explain why in some cases unidirectionality is reccomended and in others bidirectionality is reccomended instead?

Here's the wiki page (read under "concepts"):

http://wiki.elvanor.net/index.php/Hibernate

Comment: 1 and 2 must be identical, as bidirectionality applies to both sides of a relationship and one-to-many is many-to-one, depending of the point of view.

Comment: Tied closely, although not 100% identical. The way I read, 1 concerns whether it is *recommended*, 2 concerns whether it is *required*. (Of course, if it were not optional, then 1 is moot.) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that "bidirectionality" in the context of Hibernate means that in your Java classes, both sides of the relationship maintain a link to the other side. It has no impact on the underlying database schema (except in the case of indexed collections, see below), it's just whether or not you want the Java side to reflect that.

For all of your conclusions, "recommended" actually translates to "it usually ends up making sense, given your business logic, that you'd do it this way".

**You really want to read through chapters 7 and 8 of the [Hibernate Core Reference Manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/).**

1. It's recommended if you need it. A lot of convenience comes from specifying a bidirectional relationship; particularly it becomes possible to navigate the relationship from both ends in your business logic. However, if you don't actually need to do this, there's nothing to gain. Use whatever is most appropriate for the situation. In practice I've found that I want to specify both ends of the relationship to Hibernate more often than not -- but it is not a *rule*, rather, it reflects what I want to accomplish.
2. This is true. In a many-to-one (or one-to-many) relationship, it is optional. Consider the following schema:

   ```
   table: users
   fields: userId, userName

   table: forumPosts
   fields: postId, userId, content
   ```

   Where `forumPosts.userId` is a foreign key into `users`. Your DAO classes might be (getters/setters omitted for brevity):

   ```
   public class User {
       private long userId;
       private String userName; 
   }

   public class ForumPost {
       private long postId;
       private User user; 
       private String content;
   }
   ```

   As you can see, this is a unidirectional many-to-one relationship (`ForumPost`-to-`User`). The `ForumPost` links to the user, but the `User` does not contain a list of `ForumPosts`.

   You could then add a one-to-many mapping to `User` to make it have a list of `ForumPosts`. If you use a non-indexed collection like a set, this has no impact on the database schema. Merely by specifying both sides to Hibernate, you have made it bidirectional (using exactly the same schema as above), e.g.:

   ```
   public class User {
       private long userId;
       private String userName; 
       private Set<ForumPost> forumPosts;
   }

   public class ForumPost {
       private long postId;
       private User user; 
       private String content;
   }
   ```

   Hibernate will now populate User.forumPosts when necessary (essentially with `SELECT * FROM forumPosts WHERE userId = ?`). The only difference between bidirectional and unidirectional here is that in one case Hibernate fills a set of `ForumPosts` in `User`, and in the other case it doesn't. If you ever have to get a collection of any given user's posts, you will want to use a bidirectional relationship like this rather than explicitly constructing an HQL query. Depending on your inverse/insert/update/cascade options in your relationship, you can also add and remove posts by modifying the User's set of posts, which may be a more accurate reflection of your business logic (or not!).

   The reason I specified that *non-indexed* collections don't impact the underlying schema is because if you want to use an ordered, indexed collection like a list, you do have to add an extra list index field to the forumPosts table (although you do not have to add it to the ForumPost DAO class).
3. This is true, but is not a requirement and it's deeper than that. Same as above. Bidirectionality is usually present in many-to-many. Many-to-many relationships are implemented with a third join table. You specify the details of this table on both sides of the relationship. You can simply *not* specify the relationship on one side, and now it's a unidirectional relationship. Again, whether or not you *tell* Hibernate about the mapping is what determines if its unidirectional or bidirectional (in the context of Hibernate). In this case it also has no impact on the underlying schema unless you are using an ordered index collection. In fact, the [many-to-many example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch08.html#assoc-unidirectional-join-m2m) in the Hibernate reference manual is a unidirectional setup.

   In reality, it would be odd to have a unidirectional many-to-many relationship, unless perhaps you are working with an existing database schema and your particular application's business logic has no need for one of the sides of the relationship. Usually, though, when you've decided you need a many-to-many relationship, you've decided that because you need to maintain a collection of references on both sides of the relationship, and your DAO classes would reflect that need. 

   So the correct conclusion here is *not* merely that "bidirectionality is normally present in many-to-many", but instead "if you've designed a database with a join table, but your business logic only uses a unidirectional relationship, you should question whether or not your schema is appropriate for your application (and it very well may be)".
4. This is not true. Exactly the same as all the points above. If you need to navigate the one-to-one relationship from both sides, then you'd want to make it bidirectional (specify both sides of the mapping to Hibernate). If not, then you make it unidirectional (don't specify both sides of the mapping to Hibernate). This again comes down to what makes sense in your business layer.

I hope that helps. I left a *lot* of intricacies out. You really should read through the Hibernate documentation - it is not organized particularly well but Chapter 7 and 8 will tell you everything you need to know about collection mapping.

When I'm designing an application and a database from scratch, personally, I try to forget about Hibernate and the database entirely. I set up my DAOs in a way that makes sense for my business requirements, design a database schema to match, then set up the Hibernate mappings, making any final tweaks to the schema (e.g. adding index fields for ordered collections) at that point if necessary.